# Getting issue with slice on defined element

Tags: angular, pagination, undefined, slice

I an using Angular 9 and trying to implement the pagination. I am getting the below error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

My component code:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
    import { MatPaginator, PageEvent } from '@angular/material/paginator';
    import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
    
    import { TestResult } from '../models/testResult';
    import { TestResultService } from '../test-result/test-result.service';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-test-result-list',
      templateUrl: './test-result-list.component.html'
    })
    
    export class TestResultListComponent implements OnInit {
    
      testResults: TestResult[];
      dataSource: MatTableDataSource<TestResult>;
      displayColumns = ["tagNo", "testStart", "unitTestId", "isApproved", "valveTestEnvironment"];
    
      length = 100;
      pageSize = 10;
      pageSizeOptions = [1, 2, 5, 10];
    
      @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
      pageEvent: PageEvent;
    
    constructor(private readonly testResultService: TestResultService) { }
    
      loadData(pageIndex, pageSize)
      {
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<TestResult>(this.testResults.slice(pageIndex, pageIndex + pageSize));
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.testResultService.getTestResults().subscribe(result => this.testResults = result);
        this.loadData(0, this.pageSize);
      }
    }
```

I have used lice with this.testResults which is already defined as Array of TestResult Type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`testResults` variable is assigned asynchronously. By the time `loadData()` funciton is called, `testResults` isn't assigned any values yet. All statements directly depending on it should be async as well i.e, they should be inside the subscription callbacks.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.testResultService.getTestResults().subscribe(result => {
    this.testResults = result;
    this.loadData(0, this.pageSize);     // <-- inside subscription
  });
}
```

You could learn more about async data [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/6513921).